# HTML SWF file in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, flash-cs5, galaxy-tab

I am opening a url on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 in order to view an HTML file which contains a Flash site. The swf dimension is 1280px x 800px and 24 FPS.

The html file plays correctly in a PC/Mac Browser.

However in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1) Browser, the swf file is being played in slow speed.

Should I re-publish the movie with a lower FPS rate? any other solution/ideas please...

Comment: this article might help: http://articles.businessinsider.com/2010-11-11/tech/30070450_1_galaxy-tab-google-android-adobe-s-flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Smart SWF Player https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andy.flash&hl=en.

Open the file .swf

and it plays!